# what is the meaning of the "sh -c"

Tags: sh

when I want to invoke a shell command from groovy code, like "ls" or "dir" , some people say should add "sh -c" when on linux or add "cmd -c" on Windows, so it will be "sh -c ls" or "cmd -c dir", what's the meaning of this?

Answer (score 1):

`cmd /c` executes a command and then terminates the shell.
Type `cmd /?` for explanations, same for `man sh`.